# Exim: What happens after the "dot"

Tags: linux, smtp, exim, access-control-list

I'm using Exim on a Cpanel server, my server is taking too long to process incoming emails after the "dot" (".").

I'm trying to troubleshoot but having a hard time figuring the order of the ACL's

Any clue of what happens after the dot?

Comment: you can debug it using
exim -bhc fake.src.ip..address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the dot is when the email is delivered.  It is also when your email is scanned.  Things that can/do happen include:

- Any or all validation that could have happened earlier:  Sending host, Sender, SPF, greylisting, Blacklists, etc.  (Recipients are difficult to validate at this point.)
- Validate format of the message headers.
- Validate body / decode MIME parts.
- Validate MIME parts. (Content, type, etc.)
- Validate DKIM signature.
- Virus scanning.
- Scan for spam.
- Run a scan or filter process on the message.
- Write spool file or complete delivery. (Must complete before email is acccepted.)
- Send final status to sending server.

Some of these actions are sensitive to slow DNS services, load on the system, or both.

If you can find your configuration, the acl specified the `acl_smpt_data` directive will have most of the actions which can happen.  The `acl_smtp_dkim` directive may be run after the data is received.  The `demime`, `malware`, and `scan` directives will also run if specified.